# Dynamic control CheckBoxList losing style after selected index event - ASP.Net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic

I have checkBoxList control in which I am adding list items dynamically. I am applying style to some of the list items while creating. But, on the run time, when I am selecting any list Item, all the list items which have style applied to them lose their style. How can I fix it?

```
foreach (Group group1 in groups)
{
      if (wObj.Id== id.ToString())
     {
         ListItem li = new ListItem(wObj.GroupName,wObj.ID.ToString());
        li.Attributes.Add("Style", "padding-left: 25px;");
        chkBoxListWorkGroups.Items.Add(li);

     }
}
```

On the selected index event, I am just checking some condition and marking the list item checked. But the issue is style is getting lost? I mean padding of all the controls is removed? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on how and when in the [page life cycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) you are implementing your Checkboxlist, it could be due to multiple reasons. Although, most of the time it happens because when the page reloads after the "SelectedIndexChanged" event is triggered, your dynamic Checkboxlist will lose the it's [ListItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem(v=vs.110).aspx) information unless you re-generate/data bind your Checkboxlist attributes.

So, you might want to add something like this to your page load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsPostBack)
    { 
        DataBinding_Method_YouWillWrite(); 
    }
}
```

For your data bind method, one option could be to use [Viewstates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386448.aspx) to store/load the correct attributes at specific indexes in your Checkboxlist. Another option you can try would be to re-generate your Checkboxlist at every page load, you just need to make sure your Checkboxlist loads any checked listitems at page load (which can also be done through the use of Viewstates). It really depends on how you are implementing your code, there a many different ways you can go about this.